# Cloud native distributed molecular simulation environments?

Tags: simulation, scientific-computing, cloud-computing

In the long Wikipedia list of simulation [environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_simulation_software) I find only a CFD simulation for cloud.

Which would you use for molecular biology simulations with cloud computing?

Criteria: it should be possible to reproduce the [polio virus simulation](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.5.7117/full/) from 2014.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to say what particular physics/biological processes do you want to model, so I will give a more general recommendation:

- [Wiki page on software for molecular mechanics modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_software_for_molecular_mechanics_modeling)

In particular, I would point you to [LAMMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMMPS) that is suited for distributed systems and is very popular.